# Скрыть форму обратной связи в Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, компоненты

Необходимо убрать (скрыть) на сайте, работающем под админкой Битрикс, все формы, требующие ввод персональных данных.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно скрыть компонент "Обратная связь" в Битрикс, чтобы она не отображалась на сайте?

Comment: Если не хочется искать по все страницам, где этот компонент может быть вставлен, то проще всего сделать для него пустой шаблон.